# What does "project onto" mean here?

Tags: meaning

I would like to know the meaning of the word project onto, as far as I see from the context here that the word "protect onto" means that you redeem other people to have the same feeling you have.

Someone who's talking about his friend who invited him to a restaurant that he sees himself as a big deal in it

So here's the example:

Person A:

> We came here because jordan pretty much explicitly said that he is a big deal in this restaurant.

So his friend replies with that:

> I'm not concerned with a big deal! I'm concerned with a good meal, it's not all about ranks, you have this insecurity about you that you project onto others.

So now that I gave you the example does project onto here mean that person A feels the insecurity inside him and thinks that other people feel the same thing.

Comment: Did you search the web for "what does project onto mean"?  One of the results is https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/project%20onto

Comment: Not directly about your point, but "redeem" doesn't make any sense there. I'm guessing it's a mistake for "deem", but that doesn't really fit either.

Answer (score 1):

> So now that I gave you the example does project onto here mean that person A feels the insecurity inside him and thinks that other people feel the same thing.

The meaning is more exactly the following:

- person A has a feeling of "insecurity inside of him"
- person A is denying that feeling
- person A is acting like others have the same insecurity that person A is feeling in reality (even though person A is denying he has those feelings).

Answer (score 0):

Projection in psychology is where someone denies their own unconscious feelings and attributes them to others.
Your example does not clearly describe what emotion is being projected, but it sounds like the need to fill one's insecurity with big deals is being attributed to Jordan?

Comment: Look at this definition I found earlier it says: 

project something onto someone: 
to imagine that someone else experiences one's feelings, especially one's guilt or anger.

 EX: Since you project your anger onto your best friends, you imagine you have gathered a number of angry people around you. EX: You should not project your feelings onto other people.

Does that make it as how I described it to you now?